# swift& parse.com: converting String to AnyObject?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

to update the value in the table in parse I wrote this line of code:

```
                  object["score"] = self.selectedScore
```

but it gave me the error:

```
cannot assign value of type 'Int' to a value of type 'AnyObject?!'
```

So I thought of casting `self.selectedScore` to make it of type `AnyObject?!`

this is how I did it:

```
if let var castScore = self.selectedScore as! AnyObject?
{

                      object["score"] = castScore
}
```

but another error still appears which says that `castScore` is of type `AnyObject?`
while `object["score"]` is of type `AnyObject?!`

is there a way where I can `castScore` to be of type `AnyObject?!` ?

Table Track:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdOLB.png)

CODE:

```
 //test
            var taskQuery = PFQuery(className: "Track")
            //run query
            taskQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
                (success:[AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if let objects = success {
                    for object in objects  {




                        var name  = sucess["taskName"]
                        var score  = sucess["score"]

                        var unwrappedName = ""
                        var unwrappedScore = ""

                        if let name = name {
                            unwrappedName = "\(name!)"
                        }

                        if let score = score {
                            unwrappedScore = "\(score!)"
                        }


                        if unwrappedName == Track {


                                object["score"] = self.selectedScore //#ERROR

                            sucess.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                                println("Object has been saved.")
                            }



                        }
                        //trackMgr.addTrack(unwrappedName, score: unwrappedScore.toInt()!, view: false)
                    }



                }


            })

            //test
```

Comment: if u post the definition of the `object["score"]`  it will help a lot.

Comment: Updated. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I think u shoule unwrap `success!["score"]` when u use it.

```
 if let _ = sucess["score"] {

    var score = success!["score"]
}
```

Comment: Same error, cannot assign value of type 'AnyObject' to a value of type 'AnyObject?!'

Comment: post the code snippet that define `object["score"]`

Answer (score -1):

Remove the question mark at the end of the line.

```
if let var castScore = self.selectedScore as! AnyObject
{
   object["score"] = castScore
}
```

Comment: Not working, it says: cannot assign value of type 'AnyObject' to a value of type 'AnyObject?!'